# SSRS SQL script to copy a report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Is there a way to create a copy of an existing report (that is already deployed to the report server) using a SQL script? We are using SSRS 2008 R2. Thank you in advance for any help!

Possibly copying the record from the Catalog table??

Comment: Are you looking to create a copy on the same report server?  Or copy it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think so using SQL Script.

If you are using SSIS, then it can be done by using a HTTP Connection (report server URL, where the existing report is deployed) and a script task (To download to the local system).